# Inject Dependencies into Static Factory in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, service, dependency-injection, typescript, factory

I have a service written in typescript as a Class.  In this class I define a static Factory which I inject dependencies.

When I compress my application, the dependencies are being compressed and I receive an undefined provider error.

Here is my service:

```
export class TInterceptor {    
public static $inject = ['$q', '$rootScope'];
public static Factory($q:ng.IQService, $rootScope:ng.IRootScopeService)
{
  return new TInterceptor($q, $rootScope);
}
constructor(private $q:ng.IQService, private $rootScope:ng.IRootScopeService){}...}
```

Service being called here:

```
  angular
    .module('t')
    .config(config);

  function config($httpProvider:ng.IHttpProvider)
  {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(TInterceptor.Factory);
  }
```

My question is, how to I make sure the dependencies are protected from being overwritten when I compress my code?

Answer (score 1):

Register the factory. i.e,

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('interceptorFactory', ['$q','$rootScope',TInterceptor.Factory]);
```

and in the config block provide factory name:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('interceptorFactory');
```

Or supply array as well (guess it should work as well as it internally uses `$injector.invoke` it is *not a string*)

```
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q','$rootScope', TInterceptor.Factory]);
```

You forgot explicit annotation on the `config` block as well.

```
.config(['$httpProvider', config]);
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT: Update for Typescript 1.6

Now that Typescript 1.6 is out, with support of class expressions, you can use directly a class expression with a closure to use your injections:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('MyFactory', function($q, $http) {

        return class {

            constructor(data) {
                // Here you have access to $q and $http
            }
        }
    })
```

---

### Typescript 1.5

Typescript not allowing class expressions at the moment until version 1.6, I personally use this syntax for now:

```
class MyClass {

    constructor(
        private $q: ng.IQService,
        private $http: ng.IHttpService
        data) {

    }
}
```

Then I use the standard Angular factory definition that permits to use ng-annotate during the build, and I currify the class with factory injections before returning it:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .factory('MyFactory', function($q, $http) {

        var factory = MyClass

        // Return curried MyClass
        return Function.prototype.bind.apply(factory,
            Array.prototype.concat.apply([factory], arguments))
    });
```

The return line is equivalent to:

```
return MyClass.bind(MyClass, $q, $http)
```

It's less readable, but will prevent you from writing two times your dependencies each time you'll change them.

Or if you have Lodash or Underscore, you can do it in a more elegant way:

```
return _.curry(MyClass).apply(this, arguments)
```

I'm then able to instantiate my class only by providing essential data:

```
new MyFactory(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options:

1) define it on the config function

```
function config(){...}
config.$inject = ['$httpProvider'];
```

2) define when you are adding your function to the module

```
angular
  .module('t')
  .config(['$httpProvider', config]);
```